# NullPointException no metodo cadastrar

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Alguem sabe como resolver este nullPointExcetion? No segundo metodo estou usando dois comboBox

Segue a classe ClienteDAO

```
package DAO;

import Beans.ClienteBeans;
import Utilitarios.Conexao;
import Utilitarios.VerificacadoresEConrretores;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class ClienteDAO {

    public ClienteDAO() {

    }  

    public void cadastrarCliente(ClienteBeans cliente){
        try { 
            String SQLInsertion = "insert into cliente(cli_nome,cli_rua,cli_bairro,cli_telefone,cli_datacad)"
                + "values(?,?,?,?,?)";

            PreparedStatement stm = Conexao.getConnetion().prepareStatement(SQLInsertion);
            stm.setString(1, cliente.getNome()); 
            stm.setString(2, cliente.getRua());  
            stm.setString(3, cliente.getBairro()); 
            stm.setString(4, cliente.getTelefone()); 
            stm.setString(5, VerificacadoresEConrretores.converteparaSQL(cliente.getDataCad())); 
            stm.execute();  

            Conexao.getConnetion().commit();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "cadastrado com sucesso!","cadastro efetivado",1,new ImageIcon("Imagens/sucess.png"));

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Impossivel cadastrar","Erro de SQL", 0, new ImageIcon("Imagens/cancelar.png"));
        }
    }  
    // este metodo indica qual é o número do codigo do proximo cliente  que ser cadastrado
    public String proximoCliente(){
        try { 
            String SQLSelection = "select * from Cliente order by cli_cod desc limit 1;";
            PreparedStatement stm = Conexao.getConnetion().prepareCall(SQLSelection);
            ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery();
            if(rs.next()){// se existe cliente cadastrado retorna o codigo do proximo cliente
                return (Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("cli_cod")) + 1 ) + "";// o + "" transforma os valores em String
            }
            else{// se nao existe ninguem cadastrado no sistema ele será o cliente de codigo 1 
                String SQLResetIncrement = "alter table cliente auto_increment = 1;";
                PreparedStatement stmIncrement = Conexao.getConnetion().prepareStatement(SQLResetIncrement);
                stmIncrement.execute();
                Conexao.getConnetion().commit();
                return "1";
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Impossivel cadastrar","Erro de SQL", 0, new ImageIcon("Imagens/cancelar.png"));
            return "0";
        } 
    } 
    public void procurarCliente (String pesquisa, DefaultTableModel modelo){

    }
}
```

Segue a classe FuncionarioDAo

```
package DAO;

import Beans.FuncionarioBeans;
import Utilitarios.Conexao;
import Utilitarios.VerificacadoresEConrretores;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane; 

public class FuncionarioDAO {

    public FuncionarioDAO() {

    }

    public void cadastrarFuncionario(FuncionarioBeans funcionario){

        try {
            String SQLInsertion = "insertion into funcionario (func_nome , func_cargo , func_permissao , func_datacad)"
                + "values(?,?,?,?)"; 

            PreparedStatement stm = Conexao.getConnetion().prepareStatement(SQLInsertion);
            stm.setString(1, funcionario.getNome());
            stm.setString(2, funcionario.getCargo());
            stm.setString(3, funcionario.getPermissao());
            stm.setString(5, VerificacadoresEConrretores.converteparaSQL(funcionario.getDataCad())); 

            stm.execute();   
            Conexao.getConnetion().commit();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "cadastrado com sucesso!","cadastro efetivado",1,new ImageIcon("Imagens/sucess.png"));

        }
        catch (SQLException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Impossivel cadastrar","Erro de SQL", 0, new ImageIcon("Imagens/cancelar.png"));
        }
    }

    public String proximoFuncionario(){
        try { 
            String SQLSelection = "select * from funcionario order by func_cod desc limit 1;";
            PreparedStatement stm = Conexao.getConnetion().prepareCall(SQLSelection);
            ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery();
            if(rs.next()){// se existe funcionario cadastrado retorna o codigo do proximo funcionario
                return (Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("func_cod")) + 1 ) + "";// o + "" transforma os valores em String
            }
            else{// se nao existe ninguem cadastrado no sistema ele será o cliente de codigo 1 
                String SQLResetIncrement = "alter table funcionario auto_increment = 1;";
                PreparedStatement stmIncrement = Conexao.getConnetion().prepareStatement(SQLResetIncrement);
                stmIncrement.execute();
                Conexao.getConnetion().commit(); 
                return "1";
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Impossivel cadastrar","Erro de SQL", 0, new ImageIcon("Imagens/cancelar.png"));
            return "0";
        }          
    }
}
```

Segue a classe ClienteBeans

```
package Beans;


public class ClienteBeans {

    private int codigo;  
    private String nome;
    private String rua;
    private String bairro;
    private String telefone; 
    private String dataCad;

    public ClienteBeans() {

    }

    public int getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }

    public void setCodigo(int codigo) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public void setRua(String rua) {
        this.rua = rua;
    }

    public void setBairro(String bairro) {
        this.bairro = bairro;
    }

    public void setTelefone(String telefone) {
        this.telefone = telefone;
    }

    public void setDataCad(String dataCad) {
        this.dataCad = dataCad;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public String getRua() {
        return rua;
    }

    public String getBairro() {
        return bairro;
    }

    public String getTelefone() {
        return telefone;
    }

    public String getDataCad() {
        return dataCad;
    } 
}
```

Segue a classe FuncionarioBeans

```
package Beans;

public class FuncionarioBeans {

    private int codigo; 
    private String nome;
    private String cargo;
    private String permissao;
    private String dataCad ;

    public FuncionarioBeans(){

    }

    public int getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }

    public void setCodigo(int codigo) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getCargo() {
        return cargo;
    }

    public void setCargo(String cargo) {
        this.cargo = cargo;
    }

    public String getPermissao() {
        return permissao;
    }

    public void setPermissao(String permissao) {
        this.permissao = permissao;
    }

    public String getDataCad() {
        return dataCad;
    }

    public void setDataCad(String dataCad){
        this.dataCad = dataCad;
    }
}
```

Segue a classe ClienteController

```
package Controller;

import Beans.ClienteBeans;
import DAO.ClienteDAO;
import GUI.ClienteGUI;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class ClienteController {

    ClienteDAO clienteDao; 
    ClienteGUI clienteG;  

    public ClienteController() {
        clienteDao = new ClienteDAO();   
    }

    public boolean verificarDados(ClienteBeans cliente){ 
        if(cliente.getNome().equals("")){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Campo Nome nao pode ser vazio","Erro de preenchimento", 0, new ImageIcon("Imagens/cancelar.png"));
            return false;  
        }    

        if(cliente.getRua().equals("")){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Campo Rua nao pode ser vazio","Erro de preenchimento", 0, new ImageIcon("Imagens/cancelar.png"));
            return false;  
        }

        if(cliente.getBairro().equals("")){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Campo Bairro nao pode ser vazio","Erro de preenchimento", 0, new ImageIcon("Imagens/cancelar.png"));
            return false; 
        }
        if(cliente.getTelefone().equals("(  )     -     ")){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Campo Telefone nao pode ser vazio","Erro de preenchimento", 0, new ImageIcon("Imagens/cancelar.png"));
            return false; 
        }

        clienteDao.cadastrarCliente(cliente);     
        return true;
    } 
    public String controllerDeCodigo(){
        return clienteDao.proximoCliente();  
    }
    public void controlePesquisa(String pesquisa, DefaultTableModel modelo){
        //clienteDao.procurarCliente(pesquisa,modelo); 
    } 
    public ClienteBeans controlePreenchimento(int codigo){
        //return clienteDao.preencherCampos(codigo);
        return null;  // esta errado (foi apenas para nao motrar erro)
    }

    public void verificarDadosParaEditar(ClienteBeans cliente){
        //TODO
    }


}
```

Segue a classe FuncionarioController

```
package Controller;

import Beans.FuncionarioBeans;
import DAO.FuncionarioDAO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class FuncionarioController {

    FuncionarioDAO funcionarioD; 

    public FuncionarioController() {
        funcionarioD =  new FuncionarioDAO();
    }   
    public String controllerDeCodigo(){
        return funcionarioD.proximoFuncionario();  
    }

    public boolean verificaDados(FuncionarioBeans funcionario, int cargo, int permissao ){
        if(funcionario.getNome().equals("")){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Campo Nome nao pode ser vazio","Erro de preenchimento", 0, new ImageIcon("Imagens/cancelar.png"));
            return false;  
        }
        if(cargo == 0){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Selecione um cargo","Erro de preenchimento", 0, new ImageIcon("Imagens/cancelar.png"));
            return false;
        } 
        if(permissao == 0){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Selecione uma permissão!","Erro de preenchimento", 0, new ImageIcon("Imagens/cancelar.png"));
            return false;
        }

        funcionarioD.cadastrarFuncionario(funcionario);
        return true; 
    }
}
```

Segue a classe VerificadoreECorretores

```
package Utilitarios;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class VerificacadoresEConrretores { 

    public static String converteparaSQL(String data){
        //dd/mm/aaaa // data no formato brasileiro
        //aaaa-mm-dd;  //         
        return data.substring(6,10)+ "-" +  data.substring(3,5)+ "-" + data.substring(0,2);
    }

    public static String converterParaJava(String data){
        return data.substring(8, 10) + "/" + data.substring(5, 7) + "/"+ data.substring(0, 4);
    } 

   public static String retornoDataAtual(){
       SimpleDateFormat formatoData = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
       Date dataAtual = new Date();  
       return formatoData.format(dataAtual); 
   }
//    public static void main(String args[]){ 
//         System.out.println(VerificacadoresEConrretores.converterParaJava("2016/10/30"));
//    }
}
```

Segue o erro

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Utilitarios.VerificacadoresEConrretores.converteparaSQL(VerificacadoresEConrretores.java:13)
    at DAO.FuncionarioDAO.cadastrarFuncionario(FuncionarioDAO.java:28)
    at Controller.FuncionarioController.verificaDados(FuncionarioController.java:33)
    at GUI.FuncionarioGUI.B_CadastrarActionPerformed(FuncionarioGUI.java:290)
    at GUI.FuncionarioGUI.access$600(FuncionarioGUI.java:8)
    at GUI.FuncionarioGUI$8.actionPerformed(FuncionarioGUI.java:141)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
CONSTRUÍDO COM SUCESSO (tempo total: 24 segundos)
```

Comment: Adicionei amigo,

Comment: Onde é a linha 13 da classe VerificacadoresEConrretores?

Comment: Este codigo aqui: return data.substring(6,10)+ "-" +  data.substring(3,5)+ "-" + data.substring(0,2);

Comment: Checou se `funcionario.getDataCad()` realmente passa alguma coisa? Pelo erro, `data` está chegando nulo nessa linha 13.

Comment: O getData() nao tem paramentro. Eu acho que esse nulpointexception deve ser causado por causa do comboBox do metdo cadastraFuncionario

Comment: O problema é que você está passando null para o método `converteparaSQL`, e vendo seu código, o null vem de `funcionario.getDataCad() `. Porém não tem a origem desse funcionario, então fica complicado ver onde está o erro. Se possivel, adicione um **[mcve]** do código para ser possivel testar o problema.

Comment: Beleleza, vou editar a pergunta e adiconar o restante do codigo

Comment: O campo `dataCad` da classe Funcionario não está sendo preenchida, o código ainda não mostra em que momento essa classe é preenchida. Verifique se está preenchendo o objeto por completo antes de submeter a classe FuncionarioDAO.

Comment: Muito obrigado cara, era isso mesmo. Estava usando ctrl + C and ctrl V em alguns codigos acabei esquecendo de setar valaores para a datacad. funcionarioB.setDataCad(TF_Data.getText());

Comment: Mas estou outro problema, esta caidno no try cacht "Impossivel cadastra". Vou ver aqui

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olha, em geral exceções do tipo nullPointExcetion surgem quando há a tentativa de acesso há uma instância que nula.

No teu caso, o erro indicado começa em:
'Utilitarios.VerificacadoresEConrretores.converteparaSQL(VerificacadoresEConrretores.java:13)', que é uma chamada de método que recebe como parâmetro o 'funcionario.getDataCad()'.

Recomendo que olhe se há um objeto sendo retornado, por 'funcionario.getDataCad()', ou se é nulo.

Answer (score 1):

Na classe `FuncionarioDAO`, no método `cadastrarFuncionarios`, tem essa linha:
`stm.setString(5, VerificacadoresEConrretores.converteparaSQL(funcionario.getDataCad()));`

Na classe `FuncionarioController`, no método de validação, você não valida o atributo `dataCad` de `FuncionarioBeans`, logo, se esse atributo estiver nulo (que provavelmente é isso o que está acontecendo), ele passa despercebido e só aponta a exceção quando você usa esse atributo, que é no método `converteparaSQL`, na classe `VerificacadoresEConrretores`.

Implemente uma validação no seu controller, garanta que esse atributo não seja `null` e o problema deixará de existir.